# Math.pow wont work for me. Dont know why. Says cannot find symbol class.Math

Tags: java, math, exponent

My code thus far : I dont know why in the world it doesnt see the `Math.pow` or let me do the exponents. Says that it

> cannot find class Math symbol. Location : Package java.util

```
import java.util.Math;

 class Test {
        public static void main(String[] args)  {
            double result = Math.pow(4 , 2);
            System.out.printf("result");
        }
}
```

Comment: Trying to make a program to give me the squares and cubes of numbers from 1-11. Having a tough go of it...

Answer (score 3):

Math is located in `java.lang` which is imported by default, no need for the import statement.

You may also want to use `System.out.println(result)` instead of using printf which needs a format string to output your result.

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        double result = Math.pow(4 , 2);
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a shot in the dark.... did you try `import java.lang.Math`?

Comment: Everything in `java.lang` is always imported. You don't need to re-import it.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use: `import java.lang.Math`.

Then to complete the task you're after.

```
for(int i=1; i<=11; i++){  
    System.out.println("Square is: " + Math.pow(i, 2));
    System.out.println("Cube is: " + Math.pow(i, 3));
}
```

Comment: Everything in `java.lang` is always imported.  You don't need to re-import it.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but..

i don't see any answer to it so for anyone wondering I fixed this issue by **changing the name of my file**. Check to see if your file name is 'Math'. If it is, change it to something else like 'MathExample' and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

As Grewal_Creator stated above, changing the class name and file from Math to MathExample fixed it. The name Math must be clashing with something else.